# Apache ProxyRemote with Proxy-Authorization (over connect/HTTPS)

Tags: apache, https, proxy, authorization

It's easy to use the "RequestHeader append Proxy-Authorization" to create a forward proxy with no authentication that bounce over a password protected one.
But this header is not append to CONNECT requests...
I'm aware of the patch suggested at https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37355, but it does not seems to be integrated in the trunk/release branch

Is there another way to configure the remote proxy authorization credentials (and could be used in CONNECT transactions) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ported the patch from the 2005 mailing list message to the apache 2.2.X branch (last 2.2) and successfully test it.
Usage :
ProxyRemote * http://[user]:[pswd]@host:port/
(replace also the need of RequestHeader)

https://gist.github.com/131/2a5ffedc2acf61061cf39e966def2ff2

Comment: recompiling with the applied patch is not an option for me; is there any other method to have apache set the Proxy-Authorization header in the CONNECT request?

Comment: No idea whether this has been fixed upstream, sorry